# Is there a way to programmatically create very similar class properties?

Tags: python, properties, attributes, python-decorators

I've made a simple class to take in a tuple representing an array shape and assign names to the last three dimensions (depth, height, width) as class attributes. I'm interested in setting these attributes up as properties so that any changes to the instance's shape will be reflected in those attributes. This creates a situation where I have repetitive code, which will get even worse if I decide to assign more dimension names or setter / deleters in the future.

Here is my (stripped down) class:

```
class Shape():
    """A class to represent 4-dimension names of a shape tuple"""
    def __init__(self, shape):
        """Shape instance is initialized with a shape tuple

        Args:
            shape (tuple): a tuple representing an array shape
        """
        self.shape = shape

    @property
    def shape(self):
        return self._shape

    @shape.setter
    def shape(self, value):
        self._shape = value

    # ndim is needed in case number of elements in shape is not equal to 3
    @property
    def ndim(self):
        return len(self.shape)

    # width, height, depth are similar
    @property
    def width(self):
        """Last dimension of shape"""
        if self.ndim >= 1:
            return self.shape[-1]

    @property
    def height(self):
        """Second last dimension of shape"""
        if self.ndim >= 2:
            return self.shape[-2]

    @property
    def depth(self):
        """Third last dimension of shape"""
        if self.ndim >= 3:
            return self.shape[-3]
```

Instancing the class:

```
x = (4, 5)
shape1 = Shape(x)
print(shape1.shape)
print((shape1.depth, shape1.height, shape1.width))
```

> (4, 5)
> (None, 4, 5)

Setting the shape attribute to a new value:

```
shape1.shape = (3, 2, 1)
print(shape1.shape)
print((shape1.depth, shape1.height, shape1.width))
```

> (3, 2, 1)
> (3, 2, 1)

So my class works as intended, but is there a cleaner way to set multiple similar properties in a loop for example? I attempted to use setattr() in a loop in the **init**. That works for setting regular class attributes, but I couldn't find a way to set properties with it, which means that the attributes will no longer reflect updates to the instance shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each individual property can be implemented in terms of a more generic private method.

```
class Shape:
    def __init__(self, shape):
        self.shape = shape

    def _get_dim(self, i):
        try:
            return self.shape[i]
        except IndexError:
            return None


    @property
    def shape(self):
        return self._shape

    @shape.setter
    def shape(self, value):
        self._shape = value

    @property
    def ndim(self):
        return len(self.shape)

    width = property(lambda self: self._get_dim(0))
    height = property(lambda self: self._get_dim(1))
    depth = property(lambda self: self._get_dim(2))
```

You might prefer to use `operator.methodcaller` instead of lambda expressions, e.g. `width = property(methodcaller("_get_dim", 0))`

---

You can go a step further and define your own custom descriptor to use instead of `property`.

```
class Dimension:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        try:
            return obj.shape[n]
        except IndexError:
            return None


class Shape:
    width = Dimension(0)
    height = Dimension(1)
    depth = Dimension(2)

    def __init__(self, shape):
        self.shape = shape

    @property
    def shape(self):
        return self._shape

    @shape.setter
    def shape(self, value):
        self._shape = value

    @property
    def ndim(self):
        return len(self.shape)
```

Comment: Wow these are great! I think my closest attempt was similar to your first one with the property() function, but I couldn't figure out how to pass self in. I'll have to do a bit more reading into how classes work heh.

Comment: I also tried your second solution but tried my hand at blocking the "setting" of the attribute with:    

`def __set__(self, obj, value):
        raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")`

Comment: You didn't have any setters in the question, so I left them out. Also, tuples are immutable, so you'd have to change what `shape` refers to to modify it (or rebuild a new tuple). To get you started, though, you just need to define `__set__(self, obj, value)` to (re)set the tuple so that `obj.shape[self.n] == value`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Is one of your solutions more acceptable / common than the other? I feel like the first one is a bit simpler since we don't have to create a second class.